# Why does Catholicism believe in purgatory?

Tags: catholicism, hebrews

Why does Catholicism believe in purgatory if according to Hebrews we are faced with judgement after we die?

### Hebrews 9:27 And as it is appointed unto men once to die, but after this the judgment:

Answer (score 1):

Not only the Hebrews quote, but it is defined dogma in the Catholic Church that "immediately (*mox*) after death and, in the case of those in need of purification, after the purification" in purgatory, one faces his Particular Judgment (Benedict XII's [*Benedictus Deus*](http://www.papalencyclicals.net/Ben12/B12bdeus.html)).

However, venial sins or temporal punishment for already-forgiven sins might still remain. Once one has suffered and been purified of these, he enters heaven.

Comment: I've always wondered about that. I learned *mox* as "soon", not "immediately" (*statim*).

Comment: @MattGutting I added the fuller quote from _Benedictus Deus_. I think the point is that the Particular Judgment is not indefinitely delayed; the time in purgatory is finite.

Comment: Definitely much better, thanks. The bit about "after purification" clarifies things immensely.